Not able to use GIT through SSH
I've created a new SSH key on ~/.ssh/id_rsa and I added the public key (~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) on my Azure account but when I try to perform any action on git it returns the following error message:
Command to create SSH Key:
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my-email@email.com"
Also, when I try to test ssh connection with Azure git, it returns the same error message.
ssh -T git@ssh.dev.azure.com
input_userauth_error: bad message during authentication: type 7
Here's the output message for the following command
ssh -vT git@ssh.dev.azure.com
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.7, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ssh.dev.azure.com [191.235.226.19] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh_0.10.6
debug1: compat_banner: no match: libssh_0.10.6
debug1: Authenticating to ssh.dev.azure.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/luismartins/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:M0v1pzWgBZI+8xrD1u0r/dE/WSLODSRVanYDDTDC7/A
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/luismartins/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'ssh.dev.azure.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/luismartins/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 1 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:+IRMdCYTCYvqtOQbNRBrm+mbhQipS4ijp0eWgSrwS4A agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/luismartins/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:+IRMdCYTCYvqtOQbNRBrm+mbhQipS4ijp0eWgSrwS4A agent
input_userauth_error: bad message during authentication: type 7

Same problem happens if I try to connect to my Github via SSH. I believe it is an SSH issue or config but I don't have the knowledge to troubleshoot it. Still reading about to figure this out.
Any help to solve this SSH problem?
I already tried to create others SSH keys and added them into my Azure account.
Important to note that one month ago was working properly and for some reason now it's not.

Do you have any sort of firewall an antivirus or a proxy in your network?

What happens when you skip your configuration file? ssh -F /dev/null  git@github.com

No, I don't have any sort of firewall or proxy in my network.
@jeb using this command I still get the same error, input_userauth_error: bad message during authentication: type 7

Try this:
In /etc/ssh/ssh_config or ~/.ssh/config (or if your ssh_config is stored elsewhere) insert the following
#
# Optional File locations: 
#     /etc/ssh/ssh_config
#.    ~/.ssh/config
#
AllowPKCS12keystoreAutoOpen=no


It didn't work because it's not a valid config option.
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 54: Bad configuration option: allowpkcs12keystoreautoopen
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options


On what OS are you?

Im using Ubuntu 22.04
